# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1) while trying to access native method

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI with Android to use a framework. To access its code I need to access C++ code through JNI, but I'm getting the exception above. I understand the error and the memory access, but I don't know exactly why it's happening. I'm kind a new working with these technologies and after look for some answers, none have helped me.

My .h file:

```
extern "C"{
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_eegeo_MainActivity_AddNewSphere(JNIEnv* jenv, jobject obj, jlong nativeAppWindowPtr, jdouble y);}
```

My .cpp file, after namespace:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_eegeo_MainActivity_AddNewSphere(JNIEnv* jenv, jobject obj, jlong nativeAppWindowPtr, jdouble y){

    Examples::DrawSphereExample* example = (Examples::DrawSphereExample*)(nativeAppWindowPtr);
    Eegeo::Space::LatLongAltitude* example2 = (Eegeo::Space::LatLongAltitude*)(nativeAppWindowPtr);

    example2->SetAltitude(y);
    example->AddSphere((example->getLocation()), Eegeo::v3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));}
```

My activity, where it calls that method:

```
public static native void AddNewSphere(double Yposition);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.getId() == R.id.add_pin){
    AddNewSphere(id);
}
}
```

Debugging the code I notice that is the "example->AddSphere((example->getLocation()), Eegeo::v3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));" line that it can't execute, giving me this exception. I don't know if it's because the references or other thing.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: I suggest you print out the reference address and break each expression into a separate line, possibly printing the result of each portion.  This will allow you to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: Do you mean print the references that I'm using?

Comment: Yes, as a number to see if it looks valid.

Comment: How comes the C code has two parameters (`jlong nativeAppWindowPtr, jdouble y`), but Java only provides the second one?

Comment: I've followed other examples from framework. This jlong variable is used to provide a reference to determinate class. I understood that is by providing an AndroidNativeState& object (constructor), when I create my class on C++

Comment: It looks fairly suspicious that you're casting the same parameter (`nativeAppWindowPtr`) to two different types.

Comment: Sorry, @Alex Cohn. I understood your point. I've confused the params. I'll add the second one.

Comment: Thanks guys, for your help. I figure out that I was trying to do an action dinamically  but the framework I'm using does not allow it, that's why I was getting this exception. I've changed my implementation and I don't get this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that I was trying to do an action dinamically but the framework I'm using does not allow it, that's why I was getting this exception. I've changed my implementation and I don't get this error anymore.